# How to do the same calculation for multiple .dat files

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I want to do a fixed calculation step for multiple `.dat` files.

Here is my code for what I want to do with one `.dat` file i.e. the calculation:

```
    dimension t(128716),x(128716)

    open (unit=88,file='ALFA-gua-100m-2.dat',status='unknown')

    do i=1,128716
      read(88,*)t(i),x(i)

    enddo
    sum=0
    do j=1,128716
      sum=sum+x(j)
    enddo



    write(*,*)sum/128716
    close(88)
    stop
    end
```

How do I go about this? Please suggest!

Here is my code for multiple file :

```
    dimension t(128716),x(128716)

    open (unit=11,file='ALFA-gua-100m-2.dat',status='unknown')
    open (unit=12,file='ALFA-gua-100m-5.dat',status='unknown')

    do i=1,2
       ii = i + 10

      do j=1,128716
        read(ii,*)t(j),x(j)
      enddo

      sum=0
      do k=1,128716
         sum=sum+x(k)
      enddo

    enddo

    do l=1,2
       ll = l + 10
       write(ll,*)sum/128716.0

       close(ll)
    enddo

    stop
    end
```

But its not working.

Comment: Can you add your code from open file step in a loop? That should do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have modified this code but its not working.Here is my code :dimension t(128716),x(128716)

        open (unit=11,file='ALFA-gua-100m-2.dat',status='unknown')
        open (unit=12,file='ALFA-gua-100m-5.dat',status='unknown')

        do i=1,2
         ii = i + 10

           do j=1,128716
           read(ii,*)t(j),x(j)

           enddo
        sum=0
        do k=1,128716
           sum=sum+x(k)
        enddo


        enddo

        do l=1,2
           ll = l + 10
           write(ll,*)sum/128716.0

           close(ll)
        enddo

        stop
        end

Comment: You must explain what *"it is not working"* means. Never use such a phrase, it does not tell anything. Do you have some error messages? Show them all! Wrong results? Show them and explain why are they wrong and how would the correct ones look like. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] for more people to see your question.

Comment: If you want to process multiple files, the correct way is to have an external loop that processes that list (from a file, console input, etc.) and to open and close the file inside the loop, consistently re-using the same file number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An addendum to @VladimirF's answer.

To sum all the elements in an array called `x` we can simply write

```
 sumx = sum(x)
```

there is no need for the programmer to write a loop at all.  If using an array of sums, then something like

```
 sums(1) = sum(x)
```

would be appropriate.

Then to calculate the mean of an array I'd write

```
 meanx = sum(x)/size(x)
```

While I'm writing: it's not a good idea to call a variable `sum`.  There's an existing intrinsic function of that name and it will only confuse readers (though not the compiler) to have a variable of that name too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same `sum` for two iterations of the `i` loop when you have two separate loops. It will get overwritten when processing the second file.

1. You can join the loops into one.

   ```
   do i=1,2
      ii = i + 10

     do j=1,128716
       read(ii,*)t(j),x(j)
     enddo

     sum=0
     do k=1,128716
        sum=sum+x(k)
     enddo

      write(ii,*)sum/128716.0

      close(ii)
   enddo
   ```
2. You can use an array for the sums `sums(i)`.

   ```
   do i=1,2
      ii = i + 10

     do j=1,128716
       read(ii,*)t(j),x(j)
     enddo

     sum=0
     do k=1,128716
        sums(i)=sums(i)+x(k)
     enddo

   enddo

   do l=1,2
      ll = l + 10
      write(ll,*)sums(l)/128716.0

      close(ll)
   enddo
   ```